# I am trying to call a javascript function on asp button click event through code behind but i did not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a JavaScript function on my .aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}</script>
```

and i have an asp button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

on .aspx.cs page i wrote this code

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "openCity(event, 'Tokyo');", true);
}
```

but it did not worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue multiple times too and most of the time following 2 solutions helped me get the javascript working after button click:

1. Make sure that the script block is written after the control declaration in aspx page.
   e.g.

```html
<body>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
:
:
:
<!--other HTML stuff-->
<script>
//Put your script here
</script>
</body>
```

2. If above doesn't work, try using javascript timeout function.
   e.g.

   `protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, 
        this.GetType(),System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
        "setTimeout('openCity(event,\'Tokyo\'), 200);", true);
    }`

Hope this will help you for now.